# How do I print records between a start and end marker with a specific pattern using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

For example, for the following messages, I only want to extract those starting with "Receiving message", ending with "Processed", and having "Overriden" in-between.

```
Receiving message
Processing 
Processed
dummy 1
dummy 2
Receiving message
Processing
Overriden
Processed
dummy 3
dummy 4
Receiving message
Processing 
Processed
dummy 5
```

Expected output:

```
Receiving message
Processing
Overriden
Processed
```

The following will get the range, but how to filter again by matching "Overriden" and print all lines in-between?

```
awk '/Receiving message/,/Processed/'
```

Note that there are other lines between a "Processed" and the next "Receiving message" and those lines are not wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked and answered a thousand times but it's easier to write the answer than search for it so here it is again:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/Receiving message/ { f=1 }
f {
    buf = buf $0 ORS
    if ( /Processed/ ) {
        if ( buf ~ /Overriden/ ) {
            printf "%s", buf
        }
        f=0
        buf=""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Receiving message
Processing
Overriden
Processed
```

Comment: Thanks. So I have to mark the start and end and check for matching patterns myself.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk '/Receiving message/{data=""; p=1}
     p && /Overriden/{p=2}
     p{data=data $0 RS}
     p==2 && /Processed/{printf "%s", data}' file

Receiving message
Processing
Overriden
Processed
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '
/Receiving message/{
  flag=1
}
/Processed/{
  flag="";
  if(flag2){
   print val RS $0};
  val=flag2=""
}
/Overriden/ && flag{
  flag2=1}
flag{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too now for same:

```
awk '
/Receiving message/{    ##Checking here if a line has string Receiving message in it then do following:
  flag=1                ##Setting variable flag value as 1 here.
}
/Processed/{            ##Checking here if a line has string then do following:
  flag="";              ##Setting variable flag as NULL here.
  if(flag2){            ##Checking if a variable named flag2 is NOT NULL then do following:
   print val RS $0};    ##Printing the value of variable val and RS(record seprator) and current line then.
  val=flag2=""          ##Nullifying the variables named val and flag2 here.
}
/Overriden/ && flag{    ##Checking string Overriden if it present in a line and variable flag is NOT NULL then do following:
  flag2=1}              ##Setting variable flag2 as 1 here.
flag{                   ##Checking here if variable flag is NOT NULL then do following:
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0 ##Creating variable named val here whose value is concatenating to its own value.
}
'  Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.